# Where to put document title in order to be able to see it when sending links for example through Facebook? In React

Tags: html, reactjs, dom

When we send links for example in Facebook messenger, we get this:
[image: link sent in messenger - with title and image]

So it contains page title and image and as I found out the messenger engine first scans the page and then after getting the elements it renders in the chat.

I have 2 questions.

1. how to place the title in React to get the same thing for my React app - I have title tag in index.html and in componentDidMount. However, only title in index.html works. When I try to place it in render(), it also doesn't work.
2. What tag defines this image?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The 'amazon.com' at the bottom is pulled from the origin, the 'Online Shopping...' is pulled from the title, and the image is pulled from the crawler cache and can't be easily manipulated by design to prevent fake advertisement etc...

Comment: I guess it's meta tag <meta property="og:image" content="http://g-ec2.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/social/api-share/amazon_logo_500500._V323939215_.png" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"> as the image and title tag <title> Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs &amp; more</title>. I'm just wondering where can I put that in react - I tried both render, componentDidMount and componentWillMount, however, that didn't solve the issue

Comment: I believe you need to place in the index.html file in the public folder. And also keep in mind that it may take some time (like 24 hours) to update on the web cause the old values may still be cached.

Comment: Thank you all guys. right now i'm testing npm package react-meta-tags, soon will share the result.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `react-meta-tags` is just to give you a way to dynamically  manipulate the tags from within `react` if you only require a static tag you may just as well place it directly into the above mentioned `index.html`

Comment: But that won't be individual for every single page, right? I need that to be individual for each page

Comment: Correct, but if you use a package like `react-meta-tags` you can make it individual for every single page.

Comment: so you mean using it in every component? or just in index.html in public folder in script tag. just can't get it..

Comment: If you place it in the `index.html` it will just be the same for every page, if you want to have a unique title for every page of your website you need to use something like `react-meta-tags` and use it to change the title (or other desired tags) per each page.

Comment: Yes just did it. If there's a cache issue then I will wait, but for right  now react-meta-tags seems didn't solve the issue

Comment: I have had it take as long as 24 hours to update before, cause the search engine (Google) keeps a cache of this info and only checks back the source periodically.

Comment: Great! let's wait then 